# Наследование в C#: переопределение класса

Tags: c#, unity3d, ооп

Есть базовый класс — AudioPlayer и два наследуемых от него: SoundPlayer и MusicPlayer.

AudioPlayer:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class AudioPlayer : Singleton<AudioPlayer>
{
     protected AudioSource _source;

     protected partial void Awake()
     {
         _source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
     }
}
```

SoundPlayer:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SoundPlayer : AudioPlayer
{
    private void Awake()
    {
         Debug.Log("AWAKE!");
    }
}
```

Как сделать чтобы метод Awake() остался таким какой он есть в AudioPlayer'е, но при этом я мог объявить его в наследуемых классах. Тем самым переопределив их, НО не изменив инструкции из метода в базовом классе.

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужно реализовать [Шаблонный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаблонный_метод_(шаблон_проектирования)) (Template method pattern)

Comment: Просмотрел статью. Не думаю, что это то, что мне нужно, так как там метод в базовом классе указывается без тела. А я бы хотел при создании метода в дочернем классе совместить его с инструкциями написанными в базовом.

Comment: Наследники обязаны вызывать `base.Awake()`, как показано в ответе. Но это невозможно проконтролировать компилятором. Выход из положения - Шаблонный метод - он для того и сделан, чтобы нельзя было забыть вызвать базовый метод.

Comment: Есть конечно административные меры: прописать обязательность вызова базового метода в документации и проверять это на код-ревью. Но это ненадёжно, т. к. зависит от внимательности проверяющего (кто вообще читает документацию?)

Comment: Ещё вариант - написать Roslyn-анализатор и подключить его к проекту. Вариант действенный, но сложность реализации я не берусь оценить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class Parent {

    protected AudioSource source;

    public Parent (int a, float b) {
    
    }

    protected virtual void Awake() {
         source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Child: Parent {

    public Child (int a, float b, double c, string c) base:(a, b) {
    
    }

    public Child (int a, float b, double c) this:(a, b, c, "") {
    
    }

    protected override void Awake() {
         base.Awake();
    }
}
```